# Why can I not spawn a window using tkinter in Python 3?

Tags: python, tkinter

I fail to spawn a simple empty window using Python 3 on a Linux/Ubuntu computer. For example;

```
import tkinter
tk=tkinter.Tk()
canvas=tkinter.Canvas(tk, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "tkinter.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter   File "/home/anvandarnamn/myfolder/tkinter.py", line 2, in <module>
    tk=tkinter.Tk() AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk'
```

I tried a bunch of other examples copied without alterations, and it's always a similar error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You named your file `tkinter.py`. It's shadowing the built-in module of the same name, and importing itself instead. Since you didn't define `Tk` or `Canvas`, they don't exist. Choose a different name for your script to unshadow the built-in module.